# In a twocolumn book, how to add a short introduction to chapters as a one column parapgrah

Tags: sectioning, chapters, two-column

Here is what I wish to have:

```
Chapter 2 - Foo

This is an introductory paragraph, spanning over the
whole width of the document.

This is the body of the      |   due to the use of the 
chapter which is written     |   'book' class with the
on two separate columns      |   'twocolumn' option.
```

How can I achieve this layout?

Edit: I do not want to use multicol since it would be used on each chapter to explicitely specify what should be the **default behaviour** of my document (i.e. two columns). As such, the referenced question is not a duplicate.

Comment: If you are using book class `scrbook` you can do it using `\setchapterpreamble`.

Comment: Where is the MWE, that shows us all the necessary information and can be used to test our suggestions?

Comment: To have this question reopened (and not closed as too broad after reopening the dup) please add a MWE.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the KOMA-Script book class `scrbook` you can use `\setchapterpreamble` to set the columns spanning preamble. The wanted chapter head formatting can be achieved redefining `\chapterformat`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter~--~}
\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble{This is an introductory paragraph, spanning over the
whole width of the document.\bigskip}
\chapter{Title}
\Blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `multicol` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
This is an introductory paragraph, spanning over the
whole width of the document.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is something I thought about, but it seemed unwise to use a multicol for what should be the normal behaviour of my text (the specific behaviour one one column becoming the norm). So I was looking for another solution.